# Angular 4 http get request - Exception: A network error occured

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic-framework, get

I am trying to connect my ionic / angular app to a spring boot back end. I check the back end with postman and am able to get a result from the get request. When I do it with my app I get "A network error occurred". I am just learning angular - but I do another get request to firebase - and that request works fine. After doing some research ppl suggested it might be related to CORS - I have Cross Origins enabled on the spring boot app - also downloaded the extension to turn off just to make sure.

Any help would be great! Code below.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCP8z.png)

[localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znhUu.png)

[Springboot Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcnpb.png)

(from service)

```
getTimesheets() {
    console.log('Service: getTimesheets()')
    console.log('URL: ' + this.url)

    return this.http
        .get(this.url)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        });
}
```

(from timesheet.ts)

```
getTimeSheets() {
    this.timeSheetService.getTimesheets()
  }
```

Comment: did you inspect `this.url` ? What does it contain?

Comment: Can you also post `TimeSheetPage.ts` ?

Comment: 'this.url' contains: 'localhost:8080/timecard'. (It is also logged in the Error Message picture)

Comment: Thabung - I have edited my post to include the method that calls the service. But I also don't believe the problem is with the angular formatting part- I have a service that calls FireBase and it works fine. I think its some CORS / other error of that type rather than the format of the http request

Comment: It seems there's some syntax error. caused by inline template

Comment: there's no call going out to localhost:8080

Comment: When I change the URL to the firebase one the call works fine - I think it has something to do with ionic / angular 4 talking to my spring boot back end - I just don't know what that is.

Comment: I believe there's some syntax error

Comment: The syntax works when the only thing I change is the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it - I forgot the 'http://' in front of the url...